# jquery scrollto not scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my page to scrollto its elements within, as well as, offset the fixed navbar using margin.

Here is a jsfiddle displaying, the website and the problems.
http://jsfiddle.net/8tmXz/

here is the scrollto script i am using.

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(id).offset().top},'slow');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav a').click(function(){
        goToByScroll($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You have no class of `nav` anywhere....

Comment: Your criteria for "hide-on-mobile" is triggered for me in the fiddle, because the output is in one narrow pane. That makes it very difficult to test your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo/missing class for your navigation selector, consider naming your navigation with the class or edit the selector to `$('nav a')`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mh7Y8/1/)

Comment: This is correct because you are using a nav element, not a class="nav".